# How to use SSH on iPhone

Tags: ios, ssh

I am trying to create an iPhone app that connects to a Linux machine. The app should send a command via SSH to the Linux machine. I am using `system("ssh david@192.xxx.x.xx gpio write 0 0"` but this command doesn't include a password, so the log response is `access denied`. Does anyone know how to SSH into a Linux machine with a password?

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken ?

Comment: @marcio Yes it is, but it should work on non-JB idevices too if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve what you want on not Jailbroken devices is to use a lib like http://www.libssh.org to implement a ssh login within your App.
You can find examples on how to implement it there : http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html